# How to integrate Fragmentcache into WordPress

Tags: wordpress, caching, fragment

I need to use [Fragmentcache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/fragmentcache/installation/) for my logged-in users but I don't know how to use it. The installation page say

> Edit your template(s) to include FragmentCache like so:

but where put the code exactly ?

Currently I use W3C total cache, do I have to deactivate it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put that directly into your theme files, because the theme then checks for existing, cached fragments and delivers those.

That works, obviously, contrary to W3 Total Cache and the others, who cache the whole page and then deliver it (which needs no editing in the theme files).

If you want to do that, you should probably choose the way of [Child Themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), so you don´t break your original theme.